# Can a WD passport drive be unlocked from ubuntu

Tags: drive, unlock

I have ubuntu 17.10 installed in dual-boot with Windows 7 pro on AMD64.  The Windows-accessible files (NTFS) are backed up on an encrypted WD passport 4 GB usb drive.  There is a "virtual CD" visible from Windows when the drive is locked, which contains an unlocker.exe file that can password-unlock the drive under Windows.  The question is whether there is a way to run this or otherwise unlock the drive under ubuntu in order to restore files if Windows goes crump.

Comment: 17.10... you should at least upgrade to 18.04. Anyway, is that "unlocker.exe" from a 3rd party or is that part of standard MS-Windows file system?

Comment: Is it `unlocker.exe` or `unlock.exe`? The latter program seems to be provided by WD.  Anyway, you can read about the topic here:https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=12694

Comment: It is the app that is built into the drive, on a virtual CD that mounts automatically under windows.  I am not sure of the name, as I don't have the drive attached at the moment.